# UICollectionView with autosizing cells incorrectly positions supplementary view

Tags: autolayout, uicollectionview

I am using a UICollectionView with a Flow Layout and trying to get the collectionView to size the cells appropriately according to AutoLayout constraints.

While the cells work as intended, I am running in to issues with the layout of any supplementary views that I add to the CollectionView.

Specifically, the supplementaryView will be in the wrong position (i.e., the y origin is incorrect) on initial layout, before 'correcting' itself after I scroll.

[image]

For reference, here is how I am configuring my cell sizing:

**1. Set the collectionViewLayout's estimated item size**

```
let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(375, 50.0)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0
    let view = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    view.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    return view
}()
```

**2. Use subclasses of AutoLayoutCollectionViewCell**

```
class AutoLayoutCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override func preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes(layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
        layoutIfNeeded()
        layoutAttributes.bounds.size.height = systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        return layoutAttributes
    }
}
```

Note that at this point, everything works as intended.

The next step is where we fail.

**3. Provide a reference size for a header**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
return CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.frame), 30.0)
```

}

My question is: Why does this happen? How can I get this to correct? How am I supposed to handle supplementary views within a collectionView that self-sizes its cells??

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem, what solved it for me was to subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout and override the following function:

```
override func invalidationContext(forPreferredLayoutAttributes preferredAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes, withOriginalAttributes originalAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext {
    let context = super.invalidationContext(forPreferredLayoutAttributes: preferredAttributes, withOriginalAttributes: originalAttributes)
    context.invalidateSupplementaryElements(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader,
                                                at: [originalAttributes.indexPath])
    return context
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked for me. 
To invalidate layout of footers:
`context.invalidateSupplementaryElements(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter,
                                                at: [originalAttributes.indexPath])`

Comment: The bug seems to be fixed in iOS 12+ so this workaround shouldn't be needed anymore there.