# The header is not in its place in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

There is a collection with auto-sized cells, it also contains header and footer. The problem is that header and footer do not appear in their place, but if you scroll through the collection then the header and footer will fall into place. Also there is still a problem with the scroll indicator - for some reason it passes under the header, as if the header is on top of everything (even the indicator).

For information: the first section does not have a header for convenience, the size is set to 0. Also in the first section there are 3 cells.

Tell me how to fix this.

Out of place.

[image: Out of place]

Moves to a location after.

[image: Moves to a location after]

The scroll indicator passes under the heading.

[image: The scroll indicator passes under the heading]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


let cellFirst = Cell()

let randomTexts = ["Aenean dapibus urna a ullamcorper malesuada. Ut tempor. Aenean dapibus urna a ullamcorper malesuada. Ut tempor.",
                   "Sed venenatis ligula massa, a vulputate ipsum fringilla eget. Ut justo erat, facilisis id rhoncus cursus, fringilla at.",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum lobortis nibh metus, elementum tempus libero ornare vitae. Etiam sed leo pretium, consectetur turpis non, dapibus purus. Suspendisse potenti. Ut ut eros nunc. Cras nulla justo, porttitor non sapien at, iaculis.",
    "Maecenas pellentesque sed magna in congue. Sed non lacus in mi posuere scelerisque. Aenean.",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eget ex a velit tincidunt sodales. Donec elementum nisi at enim tempus, et rutrum erat semper. Phasellus ultricies est nec finibus.", "Aenean dapibus urna a ullamcorper malesuada. Ut tempor.",
    "Sed venenatis ligula massa, a vulputate ipsum fringilla eget. Ut justo erat, facilisis id rhoncus cursus, fringilla at.",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum lobortis nibh metus, elementum tempus libero ornare vitae. Etiam sed leo pretium, consectetur turpis non, dapibus purus. Suspendisse potenti. Ut ut eros nunc. Cras nulla justo, porttitor non sapien at, iaculis."]


lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 1)
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return collectionView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "Navigation Bar"

    view.addSubview(collectionView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
        collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor)
        ])


    collectionView.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    collectionView.register(Header.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header")


}



func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 5
}


public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    switch section {
    case 0:
        return 3
    default:
        return randomTexts.count
    }
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = randomTexts[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}




func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {


    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header", for: indexPath) as! Header

    header.nameTitle = "Header"


    return header


}




    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

        if section == 0 {
            return .zero
        }

        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 38)
    }
```

}

class Header: UICollectionReusableView {

```
var nameTitle: String? {
    didSet {
        nameLabel.text = nameTitle
    }
}


let nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
    label.sizeToFit()
    label.textAlignment = .left
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()




override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
}



func setupViews() {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    addSubview(nameLabel)


    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
        nameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
        nameLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 16),
        nameLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -16)
        ])
}




required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

```
class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {


let descriptionLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    label.sizeToFit()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
}

func setupViews() {

    contentView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4745098054, green: 0.8392156959, blue: 0.9764705896, alpha: 1)

    // Initialization code
    self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

    widthConstraint = contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenWidth)
    widthConstraint?.isActive = true

    contentView.autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight

    contentView.addSubview(descriptionLabel)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        descriptionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
        descriptionLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
        descriptionLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor),
        descriptionLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor)
        ])
}





required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Comment: are you using xib/storyboards for creating cells or collection view? because i also faced this issue and could find whats wrong and had to move to a tableview instead due to time constraints with my project.

Comment: created build interface programmatically

Comment: provide some code how you are creating the header in the supplementary view delegate method

Comment: this StackOverflow Answer offers a working Fix!!!: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102682/uicollectionview-with-autosizing-cells-incorrectly-positions-supplementary-view